# SwiftUI View Protocol in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to implement a Haskell counterpart of the `View` protocol of SwiftUI using type class and type family.

The [`View` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view) in SwiftUI is something like:

```swift
protocol View {
  associatedtype Body: View
  var body: Body { get }
}
```

Through type class and the associated type family, I can have:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes, FlexibleContexts, U
ndecidableSuperClasses #-}

class (View (Body x)) => View x where
  type Body x
  body :: Body x
```

which fails to compile: `solveWanteds: too many iterations (limit = 4)`.

My question is if there is a way to achieve such 'recursive' type class definition in Haskell?

Comment: This cannot be the whole story. If the only method of `View` is "get body", and the only thing that is known about the type of body is that it's also a `View`, then the only thing you can do with that body is get its body, and so on to infinity. This would never terminate, which is exactly what happens with your Haskell program. I know little about Swift, but I'm pretty sure there is something more to this.

Comment: You cannot have `body :: Body x` there, because `x` of the `Body x` cannot be determined here - which is unrelated with the recursive typeclass definition.  It seems like Swift protocol always has `Self` available, so an analogue would be `body :: x -> Body x` (should work).

Comment: Also, I think Swift's imperative-oriented framework might not be a good fit for haskell. Is there some specific thing you want to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to Haskell and have some Swift experience. Given the SwiftUI framework has a functional and declarative paradigm, I want to transfer some of my knowledge learned from Swift to Haskell. That's the reason I asked the question. I think your response makes a lot of sense, and this question can be closed.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Actually SwiftUI has some compiler magic that predefines several primitive `View`s, which are building blocks of custom `View`s. Alternatively, we can always define a `Bottom: View` instance whose body is just `self`/`this`. If you are interested, I recommend you check out [this link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/).

Comment: @YuxiangWei so, in other words, exactly like I said: this is not the whole story.